# Cannot convert value of CLLocationDegrees to expected arguments shopProperties

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, type-conversion

I have a property that looks like this:

```
class shopProperties: NSObject {
    var Latitude: CLLocationDegrees?
}
```

When i execute this code:

```
 databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let shopProper = shopProperties()

                var latitude = dictionary["Latitude"]
                var longtitude = dictionary["Longtitude"]

                shopProper.Latitude = latitude as! CLLocationDegrees
                print(shopProper.Latitude)
                self.shopProperty.append(shopProper.Latitude)
})
```

I get this error in compiler-error in build time:

Cannot convert value of CLLocationDegrees to expected arguments shopProperties

My question is how would i append this so i would be able to access it in my class?

Comment: On which line exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: On self.shopProperty.append(shopProper.Latitude)

Comment: What's the type of your `self.shopProperty` variable?

Comment: self.shopProperty is a reference to shopProperties. Initialized like this            "var shopProperty = [shopProperties]()"

Comment: So you need to append `shopProperties` type object in your `self.shopProperty`. Not the latitude inside them.

Comment: var latitude = Double(dictionary["Latitude"] as! String)! try using this please

Answer (score 0):

Your `.shopProperty` instance variable is of type `[shopProperties]` that is **Array of `shopProperties`**. So you need to append `shopProperties` type object to your array. But you are appending other type of object.

Change this `self.shopProperty.append(shopProper.Latitude)` to

```
self.shopProperty.append(shopProper)
```

**N.B.:** On a side note, start with capitals for the class names and lowercase for the property names.